Encountering a 566 status code when accessing a webpage
enter image description here
I tried to access leetcode.cn, but the browser didn’t load the CSS and displayed the message: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 566 (Waf Forbid)." I’ve already tried clearing the cache and cookies, and even used other browsers, but the problem persists.
Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
